# How can I limit the characters in one specific table row in a for loop (Python/BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, html-table, beautifulsoup, rows

In the table I'm scraping, the 2nd row is very long and I'd like to simply limit the characters that are in it since I only want the information that is at the beginning of the string. I want to scrape the other rows as they are. So my code is as follows:

```
table = soup.find(id="table3")
    table_rows = table.findAll('tr')

    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.findAll('td')
        row = [i.text.strip() for i in td]
        print(row)
```

How can I only target the second row?

The output specifically looks like:

```
["Computer price for Apple Inc. ,\n\n\nType\nForward\n\n\n\n\n\n\nBack\n\n\n\n\nDie\n\r\n...
```

So I only want to grap the `Computer price for Apple Inc.`
part, maybe there is a better way than just using character limit as a heuristic. Is it possible to specify it to grab everything before `,\n\n\n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function to separate text line. I have used `",\n\n\n"` as a separator:

```
>>> row = 'Computer price for Apple Inc. ,\n\n\nType\nForward\n\n\n\n\n\n\nBack\n\n\n\n\nDie\n\r\n'
>>> row.split(sep=",\n\n\n", maxsplit=1)[0]
'Computer price for Apple Inc. ,'
```

Comment: Thanks! but how should I write it out when scraping multiple pages, with every page having a different computer price for a different company.